# Rewrite rule for removing file extension, Webmatrix

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, webmatrix

I've using Webmatrix/IIS Express to develop a php application.While I was able to write most of the basic rules myself, I'm having difficulty with the below two items:

1. The file extension should be removed, replaced with a slash. Example below:

   http:// localhost.com / Home.php -> http:// localhost.com / home /
2. Ensure that existing folder in the root directory work. For e.g. I have an admin folder in my site root so http:// localhost.com / admin should point to it. I have only few folders so wouldn't mind if I had to create a rule for each of them.

Can anyone please specify the exact rules for the above that will go in the web.config's rewrite section?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the web.config rewrite rules that I use for this.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="GeneralRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{tolower:{R:1}}.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```